# What format are old headerless protools files?

Tags: pro-tools, file-conversion

I'm trying to convert the audio files from an old protools version where the files were headerless and lacked any other indicator of format.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the answer is sample rate: 44100, 24 bits per sample, signed integer, Big Endian.

The converter I'm using, "sox", is available on Mac via homebrew, and the commandline I used is:

```
sox -r 44100 -e signed -b 24 -B -t raw "Guitar --01 L" Guitar-01-L.wav
```

Some of these parameters might be different, depending on what choices you made for the project, but I'm pretty sure these were the default on Mac OS 9 on a PowerPC mac at the time.